# save text highlighted in pdf file using C#

Tags: c#

I built a windows form application that opens any text file (even pdf using iTextSharp Dll) and view its contents in a rich tex box, a search field where i can search for a certain pattern, all possible matches to be highlighted in "Gold" color. I created a save button.

1. how can i overwrite the text file (.doc) with the text highlighted
   by retaining the text format?
2. how can i do the same step with pdf?
   (since pdf will crash after overwriting the file)

The code:

```
private void open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tb.Clear();
        label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        if (label1.Text.Contains(".pdf"))
        {
            // create a reader (constructor overloaded for path to local file or URL)
            string location = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(location);

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);

                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append(currentText);
                reader.Close();
            }
            tb.Text = text.ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            tb.Text = File.ReadAllText(label1.Text);
        }

    }
}

private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, tb.Text);
    }
}

private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < tb.Text.LastIndexOf(sb.Text))
    {
        tb.Find(sb.Text,index,tb.TextLength,RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        tb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gold;
        index = tb.Text.IndexOf(sb.Text, index) + 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try using this to get text along with all rich text format codes?

```
string str = richTextBox.Rtf;
```

For more information and implementation guidelines with respect to this context, please refer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12932/Saving-and-Restoring-RichTextBox-Formatted-Text-Al